# Metasploit multi handler reverse tcp connection

Tags: metasploit, reverse-shell

Can we listen for 10 connections at once using any options present in Metasploit.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is "sessions". Metasploit supports multiple sessions by default.

Make sure you use `set ExitOnSession false` to ensure that the handler does not exit once it handles a session.

I cannot quickly find the maximum number of sessions Metasploit can handle by default, but I found [one reference](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/8839) where a user was able to trigger 300 sessions. The suggestion is that the limit is an OS limit and not a limit imposed by Metasploit.

Comment: @shroeder sorry for not being clear earlier.

Comment: @void_in it's all clear now :)

Answer (score -2):

Use `RHOSTS` instead of `RHOST` to engage with multiple targets at once.

Reference:-
[RHOSTS Service Enum](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/service-identification/)

Comment: RHOSTS is for specifying targets, not incoming connections